# How to define some of the same enum types in different enum classes use common lisp defenum

Tags: enums, lisp, common-lisp

sorry, I'm not good at english...
I define 2 enum use defenum

```
(in-package :useragentutils-cl)

;; name is key word so change namee
(defenum:defenum (Manufacturer (:initargs (id namee)))
         (
           (MOZILLA(13 "Mozilla Foundation"))

          )
         
         ((id)
          (namee)
          )

    
         )
```

```
(in-package :useragentutils-cl)

(defenum:defenum (RenderingEngine (:initargs (namee)))
    (
     (MOZILLA("Mozilla"))
     
     )
    ((namee))
    ())
```

when i compile RenderingEngine i got error

```
Execution of a form compiled with errors.
Form:
  (IT.UNIMIB.DISCO.MA.COMMON-LISP.EXTENSIONS.DATA-AND-CONTROL-FLOW.DEFENUM:DEFENUM
 (RENDERINGENGINE (:INITARGS (NAMEE)))
 ((EDGE_HTML 1 ("EdgeHTML")) (TRIDENT 2 ("Trident"))
  (WORD ("Microsoft Office Word")) (GECKO ("Gecko")) (WEBKIT ("WebKit"))
  (PRESTO ("Presto")) (MOZILLA ("Mozilla")) (KHTML ("KHTML")) (BLINK ("Blink"))
  (OTHER ("Other")))
 ((NAMEE)) NIL)
Compile-time error:
  (during macroexpansion of (IT.UNIMIB.DISCO.MA.COMMON-LISP.EXTENSIONS.DATA-AND-CONTROL-FLOW.DEFENUM:DEFENUM
 (RENDERINGENGINE #) ...))
Tag MOZILLA is part of enum MANUFACTURER; it cannot be added to enum RENDERINGENGINE.
   [Condition of type SB-INT:COMPILED-PROGRAM-ERROR]
```

I view the source code

```
(loop for (tag tag-id) in ',tags-specs do
              (setf (get tag '%%enum%%) e
                    (gethash tag-id id-map) (tag-of e (the symbol tag))))
```

I guess '%%enum%% is a plist with a tag, one to one, my idea is to set e is nil, when i do this
and compile RenderingEngine i got anther error

```
The constant MOZILLA is being redefined (from 13 to 7)
   [Condition of type SB-EXT:DEFCONSTANT-UNEQL]
See also:
  Common Lisp Hyperspec, DEFCONSTANT [:macro]
  SBCL Manual, Idiosyncrasies [:node]
```

so I view the source code again I got this

```
  ;; Building init code.
  (let ((tags-defconstants
         (loop for (tag tag-id) in tags-specs
               unless (keywordp tag)
               if (numberp tag-id)
               collect `(defconstant ,tag ,tag-id)
               else if (and (listp tag-id) (eq 'eql (first tag-id)))
               collect `(defconstant ,tag ,(second tag-id))))
        )
```

the defconstant define a tag.

In java enum classes can define some of the same enum types

```
package com.jq;

public enum Manufacturer {
    
    MOZILLA(13, "Mozilla Foundation");
    
    private final short id;
    private final String name;
    
    private Manufacturer(int id, String name) {
        this.id = (byte) id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}


public enum RenderingEngine {
    
    MOZILLA(13, "Mozilla Foundation");
    
    private final short id;
    private final String name;
    
    private RenderingEngine(int id, String name) {
        this.id = (byte) id;
        this.name = name;
    }

    /**
     * @return the id
     */
    public short getId() {
        return id;
    }

    /**
     * @return the name
     */
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

}
```

Comment: what is defenum ?

Comment: https://defenum.sourceforge.net/introduction.html

Comment: The site https://www.deepl.com/translator may help you write good english questions.

Comment: What is your question ? if your question is "Why do I have an error", the answer is clearly stated in the error message : "Tag MOZILLA is part of enum MANUFACTURER; it cannot be added to enum RENDERINGENGINE." By default, tags must be globally unique to avoid any misuse of them in different contexts.

Comment: @JérômeRadix
My problem is defining some of the same enum types in different enum classes use defenum

Comment: @JérômeRadix Thank you for the translation site, I've been brushing up on my English skills lately!

Answer (score 2):

The following doesn't work as you want:

```lisp
(defenum t1 (a b c))
(defenum t2 (b c d))
```

This is because `b` and `c` can only belong to one enum, when using the `defenum` library (another implementation of enumerated types could allow that). This is on purpose. You can use packages to have different symbols with the same `symbol-name`:

```
(defpackage t1 (:use) (:export #:a #:b #:c))
(defpackage t2 (:use) (:export #:b #:c #:d))
```

Here above, `t1:b` and `t2:b` are distinct symbols, with the same name. This allow you to manage the restrictions on naming in case two different enums have values that conflict. For example `color:orange` and `fruit:orange` are two symbols with the same name used in different contexts.

You would define the different enums as follows:

```
(defenum t1 (t1:a t1:b t1:c))
#<ENUM T1 (T1:A T1:B T1:C)>
```

and:

```
(defenum t2 (t2:b t2:c t2:d))
#<ENUM T2 (T2:B T2:C T2:D)>
```